# getops $OPTARG is empty if flag value contains brackets

Tags: bash, echo, getopts

When I pass a flag containing `[...]` to my bash script, `getops` gives me an empty string when I try to grab the value with `$OPTARG`.

```
shopt -s nullglob
while getopts ":f:" opt; do
  case $opt in
   f)
      str=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done
echo ${str}
```

Running the script:

```
$ script.sh -f [0.0.0.0]
<blank line>
```

How can I get the original value back inside the script?

Comment: A bash script should start with `#!/bin/bash` - what happened when you add this line to your script?

Comment: note that when I execute the script I got the following output: `[0.0.0.0]`

Comment: I found the cause but don't know how to handle it.
The script is much bigger, this is just small part.
There was a `shopt -s nullglob` at the top. This breaks the script.

Comment: Assumiong that `shopt -s nullglob` is needed - your can disable it when your run your small part of the code. what happened when you add `shopt -u nullglob` before your small part of the code, and `shopt -s nullglob` after your code?

Comment: I can put it after the flag switch-statement but not after the `echo command`.
As soon as I put the `shopt -s nullglob` the variable evaluates to the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short summary: Double-quote your variable references. And use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Long explanation: When you use a variable without double-quotes around it (e.g. `echo ${str}`), the shell tries to split its value into words, and expand anything that looks like a wildcard expression into a list of matching files. In the case of `[0.0.0.0]`, the brackets make it a wildcard expression that'll match either the character "0" or "." (equivalent to `[0.]`). If you had a file named "0", it would expand to that string. With no matching file(s), it's normally left unexpanded, but with the `nullglob` set it expands to ... null.

Turning off `nullglob` solves the problem if there are no matching files, but isn't really the right way do it. I remember (but can't find right now) a question we had about a script that failed on one particular computer, and it turned out the reason was that one computer happened to have a file that matched a bracket expression in an unquoted variable's value.

The right solution is to put double-quotes around the variable reference. This tells the shell to skip word splitting and wildcard expansion. Here's an interactive example:

```
$ str='[0.0.0.0]'    # Quotes aren't actually needed here, but they don't hurt
$ echo $str    # This works without nullglob or a matching file
[0.0.0.0]
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo $str    # This fails because of nullglob

$ shopt -u nullglob
$ touch 0
$ echo $str    # This fails because of a matching file
0
$ echo "$str"    # This just works, no matter whether file(s) match and/or nullglob is set
[0.0.0.0]
```

So in your script, simply change the last line to:

```
echo "${str}"
```

Note that double-quotes are not required in either `case $opt in` or `str=$OPTARG` because variables in those specific contexts aren't subject to word splitting or wildcard expansion. But IMO keeping track of which contexts it's safe to leave the double-quotes off is more hassle than it's worth, and you should just double-quote 'em all.

BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this; I recommend feeding your scripts through it, since this is probably not the only place you have this problem.

Comment: Great, in-depth answer! However, your proposed solution looks exactly like the line I already have. (see last line of my code block)

Comment: @Gilrich D'Oh! After copying the original line, I just clean forgot to actually apply the fix. I've edited it to correct...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `shopt -s nullglob` is needed in the bigger script.
You can temporary disable `shopt -s nullglob` using `shopt -u nullglob`

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -u nullglob
while getopts ":f:" opt; do
  case $opt in
   f)
      str=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done
echo ${str}

shopt -s nullglob
```